# Uncaught InvalidData: data did not match any variant of untagged enum ArgsEnum

Tags: javascript, error-handling, deno

I'm enthusiastic about Deno so I'm giving it a try. Found a tutorial on building a REST API [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-your-first-rest-api-with-deno-and-postgres/).

So, when I'm trying to run it, I get this InvalidData error:

```
error: Uncaught InvalidData: data did not match any variant of untagged enum ArgsEnum
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
    at async Object.connect ($deno$/net.ts:216:11)
    at async Connection.startup (https://deno.land/x/postgres/connection.ts:138:17)
    at async Client.connect (https://deno.land/x/postgres/client.ts:14:5)
    at async Database.connect (file:///Users/svenhaaf/git/deno/logrocket_deno_api/db/database.js:17:5)
```

Now, it looks to me that something is wrong when trying to connect to the database, but I can't really figure out what.

What does this InvalidData error mean? How should I fix this?

FYI my deno --version prints:

```
deno 0.42.0
v8 8.2.308
typescript 3.8.3
```

Code:
I cloned the repo from https://github.com/diogosouza/logrocket_deno_api, and in `config.js`, I edited line 1 from `const env = Deno.env()` to `const env = Deno.env`, since it looks like Deno.env became an object instead of a method.

Comment: Can't reproduce, that happens when you run the server, or when issuing a request?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused

Comment: post your complete code, because that code from repo does not compile for `v0.42.0`.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I edited my post so you should be able to reproduce it now

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial is not using versioned URLs, and `deno-postgres` version that is being used is not compatible with `v0.42.0`, since `https://deno.land/x/postgres/mod.ts` is pulling from `master`

Change `db/database.js` to import from `https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.3.11/mod.ts`, since [`v0.3.11`](https://github.com/buildondata/deno-postgres/releases) is the correct version for Deno `v0.42.0`

```
import { Client } from "https://deno.land/x/postgres@v0.3.11/mod.ts";
```

Remember to always use the version in the URL if you don't want the code to stop working when a new Deno or package version is released.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you know that v0.3.11 is the correct version for deno v0.42.0? is this documented somewhere?

Comment: You're welcome :). You should always check the release tags of the project: https://github.com/buildondata/deno-postgres/releases there you'll see that `v0.3.11` is the right one: `Support for Deno v0.42.0 `