# Can not connect to smtp server deno

Tags: javascript, email, smtp, deno

i'm quite new to deno and i was trying to send mails with it, using module smtp-client.

```
import { SmtpClient } from "https://deno.land/x/smtp/mod.ts";

const client = new SmtpClient();

await client.connect({ // this is the line where error is thrown
  host: "smtp.google.com",
  port: 465,
  username: "<MY EMAIL>",
  password: "<MY EMAIL PASSWORD>",
});
// etc...
```

But it gives me an error, before even trying to make request (`sendMail`).

```
[0] error: Uncaught InvalidData: data did not match any variant of untagged enum ArgsEnum
[0]     at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
[0]     at Object.sendAsync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:98:10)
[0]     at async Object.connect ($deno$/net.ts:180:11)
[0]     at async SmtpClient.connect (https://deno.land/x/smtp/smtp.ts:28:18)
[0]     at async file:///C:/path/to/server/controller.js:5:1
```

Comment: That module is not updated, the last release, v0.4.0, only supports Deno 0.42.0. I suggest you use another module.

Comment: Can you check solution from this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757437/uncaught-invaliddata-data-did-not-match-any-variant-of-untagged-enum-argsenum

Answer (score 1):

smtp server for gamil (AFAIK) is smtp.gmail.com

Then you have to activiate on gmail "Less Secure Applications" to allow smtp client to connect

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in 2023, and the "Less Secure Applications" option is no longer available.

You have to enable 2-Step Verification and then get an Application Specific password.

1. Set up 2-Step Verification on the Google Account you want as your SMPT https://myaccount.google.com/u/5/signinoptions/two-step-verification
2. Scroll to the very bottom of the 2-Step Verification page and find "App Passwords"
3. Add a new app like "example.com SMTP service"
4. Copy the new App Password and use that one as the SMTP service password, instead of the normal account password